# How to get crash reporting from beta testers' devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I see a lot of posts about beta testing from a technical standpoint (tools, deployment, etc) but I haven't been able to find anything regarding any code you can use to retrieve useful crash information from a beta tester's iPhone.

What do most people do in this case? I've heard of some people sending emails every time their apps crash on a device.

Is there an elegant method of receiving error/crash information from a tester's device programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this from apple's iOS reference Library:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2008/tn2151.html

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna check out this [CrashReporter framework](https://github.com/TheRealKerni/CrashReporterDemo) that allows you to receive crash reports instantly and group them to clusters on the server side.